# Como criar um object em uma Linq.Expressions.Expression e adicionar propriedades dinamicamente ao mesmo em C#

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda, entity-framework-core

Olá, estou criando uma biblioteca de `DataAnnotations` para extender o EntityFrameworkCore com estruturas que hoje só existem usando a FluentAPI. Em uma delas, estou tentando recriar esse bloco da FluentAPI:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace Test 
{
    public class A
    {
        public int B{ get; set; }
        public int C{ get; set; }
    }
    public class TestContext: DbContext
    {
        DbSet<A> A { get; set; }
        protected override OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder mb)
        {
            mb.Entity<A>().HasIndex(x => new { x.B, x.C}).IsUnique();
            // ... muitas outras implementações usando o model builder aqui =[
        }
    }
}
```

Para fazer isso, Vou criar um atributo abstrato que será rastreado por uma Factory onde, essa factory será chamada dentro do `OnModelCreating`, assim:

```cs
namespace Test 
{
    public SpAttributeFactory 
    {
        private DbContext context;
        private ModelBuilder builder;

        public SpAttributeFactory(DbContext context, ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.builder = builder;
        }
        public void Run() { /* ainda vou implementar e não tem relação à questão */ }
    }
    public class TestContext: DbContext
    {
        // ... nova implementação com a factory
        protected override OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            new SpAttributeFactory(this, builder).Run();
        }
    }
}
```

E a partir desse atributo, vou criar múltiplos atributos que fazem as implementações da FluentAPI diretamente no model assim como as outras DataAnnotations que existem, Assim:

```cs
namespace Test 
{
    public abstract class SpAttribute : Attribute
    {
        protected SpAttribute(Type baseType) => BaseType = baseType;
        protected Type BaseType { get; set; }
        protected abstract void Run(params object[] args);
    }
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public abstract class SpTableAttribute : SpAttribute
    {
        protected SpTableAttribute(Type baseType) : base(baseType) { }
    }
    public class SpIndexAttribute : SpTableAttribute
    {
        public SpIndexAttribute(Type baseType, params string[] columns) : base(baseType)
        {
            Columns = columns;
        }

        public bool Unique { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> Columns { get; set; }

        protected override void Run(params object[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                ModelBuilder builder = null;
                DbContext context = null;
                IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> props = null;

                // get dependencies from args

                foreach (var arg in args)
                    if (arg is ModelBuilder)
                        builder = (ModelBuilder)arg;
                    else if (arg is DbContext)
                        context = (DbContext)arg;

                // try get entity or catch error
                var entity = builder.Entity(BaseType);

                // get properties by sended name in attribute

                props = BaseType.GetProperties()
                    .Where(x => Columns.Contains(x.Name));

                // checked if number of props is same of number of colum sended
                if (props.Count() != Columns.Count())
                    throw new ArgumentException(
                        "As colunas informadas não coincidem com as propriedades públicas da classe"
                    );

                // building lambda linq method

                var lParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "x");

                /*
                    Aqui está o problema... preciso instanciar no `body` da
                    função linq um "new {}" e, para cada PropertyInfo 
                    encontrada, eu devo criar uma propriedade no objeto anônimo
                    e atribuir essa propriedade. Ex:

                    .HasIndex(x=> new { x.B, x.CB })
                */

                var indexBuilder = entity.HasIndex();

                if (Unique) indexBuilder.IsUnique();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
}
```

O que eu preciso fazer para conseguir criar uma Linq.Expression que retorne um objeto contendo uma série de propriedades que será passadas ao atributo?

**Extra**

O resultado dessa implementação será a possibilidade de fazer isso:

```cs
namespace Test 
{
    [SpIndex(typeof(A), "B", "C", Unique = true]
    public class A 
    {
        public int B { get; set; }
        public int C { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@LeandroLuk, não consegui testar aqui, mais da uma olhada se te ajuda este método que fiz baseado em uma resposta do SOEn:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35342955/dynamically-creating-an-expression-which-selects-an-objects-property

```
public LambdaExpression ToDynamicLambda()
{
    var itemParam = Expression.Parameter(BaseType, "x");
    var members = Columns.Select(f => Expression.PropertyOrField(itemParam, f));
    var addMethod = typeof(IDictionary<string, object>).GetMethod(
                "Add", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(object) });


    var elementInits = members.Select(m => Expression.ElementInit(addMethod, Expression.Constant(m.Member.Name), Expression.Convert(m, typeof(Object))));

    var expando = Expression.New(BaseType);
    return Expression.Lambda(Expression.ListInit(expando, elementInits), itemParam);
}
```

Comment: Isso resolveu meu problema, mas acabou gerando outro na minha forma de trabalhar. Minha solução então foi em cada classe que eu tivesse que criar uma config especial, eu adicionava uma classe extra que extendia a `IEntityTypeConfiguration<>`. Depois no meu DbContext eu fiz isso `builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());`